# Getting @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars warning occurs even though the variable is used

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, eslint

I keep getting @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars warning occurs even though the variable is used.

[image]
I get a warning even though I use a variable as in the picture above.
I wonder why these warnings are happening.

I'm using version 5.0.0 of @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin and @typescript-eslint/parser, and Typescript version 4.3.5. (with Visual Studio Code editor)

Also, my tsconfig.json is as follows.

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "strictBindCallApply": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false
  },
  "typescript.preferences.importModuleSpecifier": "relative"
}
```

Comment: Try restarting VS Code.

Comment: @RitikBanger unfortunately not resolved.

Comment: could you share where module and other imports are used?

Comment: @RitikBanger You can tell by looking at the image. For example, UserService is used by providers.

Comment: Try removing the imports and re-import them from the usage. Use ctrl + space to auto-import in vscode

Comment: @RitikBanger unfortunately not resolved also.

Comment: "typescript.preferences.importModuleSpecifier": "relative" change relative to absolute in tsconfig

Comment: @RitikBanger I've tried changing and deleting the "typescript.preferences.importModuleSpecifier" property value before, but the result is the same.

Comment: add this:  "include": ["src"] in your tsconfig

Comment: {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "baseUrl": "src"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}

Comment: @RitikBanger The warnings from libraries like class-validator didn't go away, but the warnings went away when importing local files. thank you! I need to find out more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error can be resolved by adding the 'include' property.

`include` specifies an array of filenames or patterns to include in the program. These filenames are resolved relative to the directory containing the tsconfig.json file.

```
{
  "include": ["src/**/*", "tests/**/*"]
}
```

Which would include:

```
├── scripts                ⨯
│   ├── lint.ts            ⨯
│   ├── update_deps.ts     ⨯
│   └── utils.ts           ⨯
├── src                    ✓
│   ├── client             ✓
│   │    ├── index.ts      ✓
│   │    └── utils.ts      ✓
│   ├── server             ✓
│   │    └── index.ts      ✓
├── tests                  ✓
│   ├── app.test.ts        ✓
│   ├── utils.ts           ✓
│   └── tests.d.ts         ✓
├── package.json
├── tsconfig.json
└── yarn.lock
```

[Reference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig)